# How do I set the base URL in my Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to provide an entry to users, so they can enter the company URL, IP etc. When this is entered the authentication (password/username) takes place.

In code behind i currently set there.

```
public class RestService
{
    private const string BaseURL = "http://160.190.1.4"; <--not real.
}
```

On my login form there will be an area to enter the base URL, this base URL will be included in my rest calls to the API.

I think this strategy is popular among Enterprise applications/ software. But how would you re set the Base URL string ? P.S. i wont be using IP Addresses just at this time I am using a Virtual Machine to point my app at.

> So how would you initialize the URL to my BaseURL field?

any information would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Settings plugin and save your base url at first time. When your app is loaded on the first screen you can get value from textbox and set it to Setting. Then you can make request using that url in further application. [Setting Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin).

Comment: Would this still allow me to change to a different value later on?

Comment: Im not sure how this would work but will have a look

Comment: Yes you can change values later on.

Comment: this seems the best way, hopefully there are more answers. Im also wondering if the Essentials package would be better? or is that just a collection of all the creators packages?

Comment: Yes. There may be some other ways, but this is the small and easiest way to save anything at application Level. You can download source code of that plugin and implement it in your way. If you don't want to use third party package.